# Magento 2 - Custom Payment Module Frontent Error

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento2

I have created a custom payment module in Magento 2 and I have made it accessible [here](https://github.com/tshepo-desh-mathabe/MyGate) in GitHub. The problem I'm sitting with is that, when I view my cart, I see the text **Estimate Shipping and Tax** after adding my custom payment module and there is no errors shown on the console log.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to resolve this, I should be able to see my
cart (instead of Estimate Shipping and Tax text)